# What is the maths behind the Solver function in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, solver

I am currently using the Solver function in Excel to approximate 2 *sin* functions. The results are pretty good, however I want to understand how it exactly it works. I'd greatly appreciate any sources I can read from as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment but it may not count as a full answer:

[Microsoft says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040) the tool was developed by Frontline Systems so go to their website for more details in how it works:

> For more detailed help on Solver contact:
>
> Frontline Systems, Inc.
> P.O. Box 4288
> Incline Village, NV 89450-4288
> (775) 831-0300
> Web site: http://www.solver.com
> E-mail: info@solver.com
> [Solver Help at www.solver.com](http://www.solver.com/suppstdsolver.htm).
>
> Portions of the Solver program code are copyright 1990-2009 by Frontline Systems, Inc. Portions are copyright 1989 by Optimal Methods, Inc.

You can dig around [in that site](https://www.solver.com/excel-solver-algorithms-and-methods-used) to find some information about what algorithms is uses:

> The GRG Nonlinear Solving Method for nonlinear optimization uses the
> Generalized Reduced Gradient (GRG2) code, which was developed by Leon
> Lasdon, University of Texas at Austin, and Alan Waren, Cleveland State
> University, and enhanced by Frontline Systems, Inc.
>
> The Simplex LP Solving Method for linear programming uses the Simplex
> and dual Simplex method with bounds on the variables, and problems
> with integer constraints use the branch and bound method, as
> implemented by John Watson and Daniel Fylstra, Frontline Systems, Inc.
>
> The Evolutionary Solving Method for non-smooth optimization uses a
> variety of genetic algorithm and local search methods, implemented by
> several individuals at Frontline Systems, Inc.

I searched the web for more details on those algorithms and found [at least one page](https://engineerexcel.com/excel-solver-solving-method-choose/) that explains how each works although it doesn't get into the gritty math. You can probably find more on your own now that you know the names of the algorithms.

Comment: Can't vote as I have a new account, but thanks for your answer! Think I can figure it out from here!